# DbGeometry vs DbGeography difference

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, gis, spatial, sqlgeometry

DbGeometry provides a base class for objects that define geometric shapes.

DbGeography represents data in a geodetic (round earth) coordinate system.

But these classes has similar static methods. For example:

```
DbGeometry.FromText("POINT(12.803099 9.405076)", 4326);
DbGeography.FromText("POINT(12.803099 9.405076)", 4326);
```

Both of them takes coordinateSystemId. But DbGeometry does not care about coordinates. Why all of them contains coordinate system information.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "DbGeometry does not care about coordinates"? DbGeometry does care about coordinates, eg there is a property XCoordinate which (from the documentation) returns "the X coordinate of this DbGeometry value, if it represents a point". Also, please clarify if this question is regarding DbGeography/DbGeometry in Namespace System.Data.Spatial in assembly System.Data.Entity? Or Or namespace System.Data.Entity.Spatial in EntityFramework (version 6).